# How to capture EventDispatchAction in Struts from Hyperlink?

Tags: jsp, struts

I have a JSP page where there are multiple options for search, i.e. "search by Application id", "search by Applicant name" etc. I have used struts EventDispatchAction to catch the event generated by a particular submit button. This is working fine. Below is the snap of the struts-config file for this:

Now I am facing problem in paginating the search results, because I am not able to generate event when the page numbers are clicked. They are hyperlinks. Below is the code used to generate the page numbers:

```
<c:forEach items="${pagelist}" var="emp"> 

<td><a href="#?page=${emp}">${emp}</a></td> 
</c:forEach>
```

I am not sure what to put in place of # to generate event for EventDispatchAction. The ActionClass to capture the submits is given below:

```
public class SearchApplicationAction extends org.apache.struts.actions.EventDispatchAction {

      public ActionForward idSubmit(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

    List applist = null; 

        SearchApplicationForm searchApp = (SearchApplicationForm) form;
        String idText = searchApp.getAppId();
        int appId = Integer.parseInt(idText);


        UserManager manager = new UserManager();
        applist = manager.ViewApplicationById(appId);

        sess.setAttribute("applicationList", applist);
        return mapping.findForward("idSubmit");

    }

      public ActionForward nameSubmit(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        List applist = null;

        SearchApplicationForm searchApp = (SearchApplicationForm) form;
        String name = searchApp.getApplicantName();


        UserManager manager = new UserManager();
        applist = manager.ViewApplicationByName(name);


        sess.setAttribute("applicationList", applist);
        return mapping.findForward("nameSubmit");
    }
}
```

Any help in this regard will be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Miguel. Actually the problem is not in using actions with links but to catch the appropriate event. When a user clicks on any of the search options then the event is handled in SearchApplicationAction. But after paginating the search results, I have to generate those actions whenever someone clicks on the page numbers. If I hardcode the action in hyperlink then it works.

```
 <td><a href="searchApplication.do?nameSubmit&page=${emp}">${emp}</a></td>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the struts taglib: `<html:link>` in order to build links related to struts actions. See this: http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#html:link